# Is there a callback that a linux kernel driver can have invoked when the RTC is changed?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am writing a linux kernel driver which is sensitive to the real time clock and I would like my driver to be notified in some way--perhaps via callback--that the RTC has been updated. Is there a mechanism to do this?

I am working with a variety of kernel versions from 3.4 to 4.4.

Comment: There is not such notification as this is very unusual. However, if it is related to a specific RTC model, you can make the driver call you driver code.

Comment: Apparently it is possible for a userspace program to listen to RTC changes via timerfd: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html . Is it possible for kernelspace to use this mechanism?

Comment: What do you need exactly? Knowing when the user or NTP is changing the time of the RTC or knowing when a second passed?

Comment: I need to know when the user or NTP changes the RTC.

Comment: I confirm there is no notification or callback for this kind of event.